# Generate a time series using vectorization

Tags: r, loops, time-series, vectorization

I want to generate an AR(2) process (autoregressive process of 3rd order) with 50 values:

[image: formula]

Where: Y(t) is a time series and E(t) the error term.

The error term values are randomly picked from a standard normal distribution and we assume the following:

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

[image: formula]

As a former Java programmer and relatively new R convert, the use of a loop comes very obvious to me and the code down below is how I would go about it. However, I have been trying to shift to the vectorization paradigm and have been looking for a way to perform this task 'the vectorized way'. Thank you very much for your assistance.

```
set.seed(123) # Reproducible
u <- rnorm(50) # Vector of randomly generated numbers for the error term
Y <- vector(length = 50) # Vector that will contain the generated time series values
a1 <- 0.25 # alpha 1
a2 <- 1.17 # alpha 2
# Based on the assumptions made, we can derive the values for the first 2 time periods:
Y[1] <- a1*0 + a2*0 + u[1]
Y[2] <- a1*Y[1] + a2*0 + u[2]

# The following "loop" generates the remaining values
i <- 3
while(i <= 50){
  Y[i] <- a1 * Y[i-1] + a2 * Y[i-2] + u[i]
  i <- i+1
}

Y
 [1]   -0.5604756   -0.3702964    0.8103777   -0.1601440    1.0373937    1.7870450    2.1214280    1.3561384    2.1342525    1.6745831
[11]    4.1398030    3.3540268    6.0828477    5.5556059    7.9499921   10.2744701   12.3679588   13.1465026   18.4584934   19.5232400
[21]   25.4094235   28.9765717   35.9471640   42.1604887   51.9732648   60.6343946   76.8051055   90.2968912  111.2980593  134.7256925
[31]  164.3266167  198.4156429  242.7611779  293.7147301  358.2808418  433.9050850  528.2187738  639.6617312  777.6254355  942.4301133
[41] 1144.7345808 1388.6189605 1685.2288034 2048.1603406 2484.9657471 3016.4659267 3661.1235209 4444.0793591 5395.3143244 6548.3180622
```

Comment: You *could* use `arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.25,1.17)),n=50)` (see `?arima.sim`) for this specific question. However, `arima.sim()` will quite rightly complain that your AR(2) parameters yield a non-mean-stationary model (as you could already suspect from the output of your loop) and return an error, so I'd suggest you think about whether you'd like to change your parameters.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the `a2` parameter makes the model non-mean stationary; however, this is not really the problem. This is just a simplified example of something else I would like to do. The vectorized operation I should use in this case is really what I am looking for without necessarily using a package. Thank you very much for your input though.

Comment: Vectorization is inherently less trivial for simulating ARMA models than for other operations. You can't just "perform an operation separately for each component", as for `c(1,2)+c(3,4)`, since later realizations of an ARMA process will, by definition, depend on earlier ones. Better to use some other examples to study vectorization in R ;-)

Comment: That's exactly what I thought and exactly the reason why I posted the question. Thank you once again for sharing your expertise with me.